# Data migration in laravel

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration

What is best practices for **migrating data** after a table gets changed?

I mean, when I alter couple of columns , or when I wanna drop a useless table, I need to migrate data into another table or split it into couple of tables.

My current approach is using **commands**.
Is there any better solution for this?
can I use migration instead of using commands?
Aren't commands just for Schema building?

Comment: [laravel migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)  can be used for all kind of db structure operations. You may create tables, alter tables, rename tables and many more using laravel migrations.

Comment: Yes, you can do them inside the migrations, but do not use model classes as these might change, and the migrations should be able to live in all states of the app. So use DB::table(.. instead.